# How do I define a one-to-one relationship over a one-to-many relationship in a relational database?

Tags: database, relational-database, database-schema

I'm creating a database schema with the following tables (sorry for the bad pseudocode):

```
User
====
user_id, PK

Collection
==========
collection_id, PK
user_id, FK(User->user_id)

Issue
=====
issue_id, PK
collection_id, FK(Collection->collection_id)
```

There is a one-to-many relationship from User to Collection, and also from Collection to Issue. So, a single user may maintain multiple collections, each with many issues.

**The problem:** I would like to designate a "default" collection to be displayed when the user first logs in to the application. For the record, I'm doing this in the Django framework, but I'm more interested in the elegant platform-independent solution. When I try to make a column in User that is a Foreign Key to Collection, it complains that Collection does not exist yet (I suppose because User is created first). I *could* add a "default" boolean column to Collection and enforce through my application that only one record per User be "true", but that seems inelegant. I could also have a separate table, say, User_Default_Collection, which has user_id as a Foreign, Unique Key, and a collection_id column which is a Foreign Key to Collection. But I'm certain this is also less than 3rd normal form. Any suggestions?

Comment: Sorry, was replying on mobile. My understanding is that normalization applies to an entire database, not just a single table.

Comment: As for your other comment I'm not sure what you're asking. A User **must** have a default Collection, and there may be only one.

Comment: We say that a database is in a certain normal form to mean that all its tables are in at least that normal form. We say that a table is in a certain normal form based on constraints that it is subject to per functional dependencies and join dependencies. Which are not inter-table constraints. Suggest you find out more about normalization. (From a college/university textbook/slides/course. Many are online.) Re my last PS: Ok, users are 1:1 with collections. Then the rest of that comment applies.

Comment: No, Users are one-to-many with Collections. But they are 1:1 with a default Collection.

Comment: I thought I was pretty clear when I said "There is a one-to-many relationship from User to Collection, and also from Collection to Issue. So, a single user may maintain multiple collections, each with many issues." The goal is to "mark" exactly one of these collections per user as a "default," that is, to be displayed by default when opening the application. Perhaps the title of my question is misleading.

Comment: My mistake, I meant to say, users are 1:1 with default collections. Thanks for the clarifications. Re your title, it's not clear it means, because it's not clear what "over" means, even given the question body. It seems to just be vaguely used as "in addition to".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to enforce that every user must and will always have his "default" collection, then because of the obvious cycle in the inclusion dependencies you are forced into either deferred constraint checking (if your DBMS allows the FK cycle to be declared in the first place) or application-enforced integrity.

If you can tolerate users not having any default collection at all, then create a separate table DFT_COLL(userid, dft_coll_id) with key userid and FK's to both USER and COLLECTION.

If it gives you trouble in cases when a user has no default collection, maybe this can still be addressed by having the system just pick one (e.g. the one with the lowest [or highest] id) and implement this with a UNION view (so that if you need the default then you read the UNION view and you're guaranteed (*) to get *some* result).

(*) If the user has a collection at all, that is.  Note that requiring a default collection and requiring that to exist, implies requiring at least one collection per user.  (And the corollary of this is that if it must be allowed for a user to have no collection at all, it is nonsensical and a contradiction to require him to have a default one.)

Comment: I like this answer and I'm going to go with the secondary table. At the application level, I'm making a collection at the time a user is created, so there will always be at least one (and I won't allow the user to delete their last collection).

Answer (score 0):

The most plausible solution i think would be:

1. Add nullable "default" field to Collection table
2. Create UNIQUE constraint for used_id and default

Keep "true"-s and NULLs (no false's) in "default" column.

This will not allow for multiple Collections associated with the same user_id to have the same "default" value other than null. You don't need to develop any application logic. However, this design would not force you to always have a default collection for a user.

Comment: But is this still third normal form? I'm not sure it is.

Comment: Not really. But an extra table solution requires to keep it in sync with Collection table (what if user-collection link is set in DFT_COLL, but not in Collection?), and I consider it a greater evil.